# PowerMock with EasyMock, expectation returns null instead of a mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, easymock

Looking for some guidance as to why an expectation returns null instead of the requested mock.  The mock in question is a Future and is following the same pattern as other mocks that get returned correctly.

To provide all the information to someone with experience with powermock and easymock, I've included all the code, both code under test and the test code that sets up the mocks and behaviours.  The expectation in question is

```
EasyMock.expect( mockAsyncClient.execute( EasyMock.isA( HttpGet.class ),
EasyMOck.isA( HttpClientContext.class ), isNull() ).andReturn( mockFuture )
```

which produces a null instead of returning a mocked Future.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

p.s. there is an awful lot of mock setup required to test this function, which I hope doesn't hinder evaluating the problem.  Any advice to remove unnecessary mocking infrastructure would be appreciated.

Here's the code under test

```
    public <T> T getResponse( ResponseHandler<T> responseHandler )
    throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{
    String connectTo = buildUri();

    try( CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient =
                                             HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                                                             .setConnectionManager( connManager )
                                                             .build() ) {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet( connectTo );
        HttpClientContext ctx = HttpClientContext.create();

        addHeaders( request );

        httpClient.start();

        Future<HttpResponse> futureResponse = httpClient.execute( request, ctx, null ); //<-- this line executes using a verified HttpClient mock but returns null

        HttpResponse response = futureResponse.get();

        return responseHandler.handleResponse( response );
    }
}
```

test code:

```
    @Test
@PrepareOnlyThisForTest( { HttpAsyncClients.class, HttpAsyncClientBuilder.class } )
public void testGetResponseCallsResponseHandler()
    throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{
    // create mocks to be used when exercising the code under test
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient mockAsyncClient =
                                             EasyMock.createMock( CloseableHttpAsyncClient.class );

    PowerMock.mockStatic( HttpAsyncClients.class );

    HttpAsyncClientBuilder mockClientBuilder =
                                             PowerMock.createMock( HttpAsyncClientBuilder.class );
    HttpAsyncClientBuilder mockClientBuilder2 =
                                              PowerMock.createMock( HttpAsyncClientBuilder.class );

    HttpResponse mockResponse = PowerMock.createMock( HttpResponse.class );
    StatusLine mockStatusLine = PowerMock.createMock( StatusLine.class );
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    Future<HttpResponse> mockFuture = PowerMock.createMock( Future.class );

    // set up expectations that use the mocks
    EasyMock.expect( HttpAsyncClients.custom() ).andReturn( mockClientBuilder );
    EasyMock.expect( mockClientBuilder.setConnectionManager( EasyMock.isA( NHttpClientConnectionManager.class ) ) )
            .andReturn( mockClientBuilder2 );
    EasyMock.expect( mockClientBuilder2.build() ).andReturn( mockAsyncClient );

    mockAsyncClient.start();
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();

    EasyMock.expect( mockAsyncClient.execute( EasyMock.isA( HttpGet.class ),
                                              EasyMock.isA( HttpClientContext.class ),
                                              EasyMock.isNull() ) )
            .andReturn( mockFuture );

    EasyMock.expect( mockFuture.get() ).andReturn( mockResponse );

    EasyMock.expect( mockResponse.getStatusLine() ).andReturn( mockStatusLine );
    EasyMock.expect( mockStatusLine.getStatusCode() ).andReturn( 200 );

    mockAsyncClient.close();
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();

    PowerMock.replayAll();

    ClientConfig cfg = new ClientConfigBuilder().build();
    RestClient client = new RestClient( cfg );

    int statusCode = client.getResponse( new ResponseHandler<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer handleResponse( HttpResponse response )
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
        {
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            return statusLine.getStatusCode();
        }

    } );

    PowerMock.verifyAll();

    assertEquals( "status code incorrect", 200, statusCode );
}
```

Comment: null is usually returned when an expectation is not matched, which would suggest to me that some of your parameter matchers are not matching how you expect them to. I would suggest changing the to anyObject() matchers and seeing if that helps, then you can debug which ones are not the types you're expecting. Also, as there's a lot of mocking going on, it's possible some of your other expectations aren't matching and are returning nulls, so debugging through and seeing which variables are null will also help. One final question, where does connManager come from?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  connManager is a real type that's built by the class during construction.  As for other nulls, I've verified that all is good, by commenting out those expectations for the future.  All expectations are satisfied, including stop() call that's implicit in the try-with-resources block.  I will try the anyObject() as you suggest.  I had tried anyObject( <type.class>) in place of isA(...) but it had the same behaviour.  Also tried returning an IAnswer(){} but the answer() method doesn't get called.  Btw, during a non-mocked integration test, the code works.

Comment: Tested anyObject() but the behaviour is the same.  To make it compile, though, I had to cast the first anyObject() reference to HttpGet, so the expectation could resolve which overloaded method to call.  I have a feeling that type erasure is perhaps causing the EasyMock expectation to fail.  Never seen this behaviour before and mocking out overloaded functions is not a new thing.

Comment: EasyMock.expect( mockAsyncClient.execute( EasyMock.isA( HttpGet.class ),
                                                  EasyMock.isA( HttpClientContext.class ),
                                                  EasyMock.isA( FutureCallback.class ) ) )
        .andReturn( mockFuture );

Results in:

 Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(GET http://127.0.0.1:80/ HTTP/1.1, org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext@63dda940, null)
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()

Comment: Verified that the execute() method mocks match the signature types.  Powermock bug?  Besides a null reference returning from the execute() method, the test fails on the expectation for this method:
...
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(GET http://127.0.0.1:80/ HTTP/1.1, org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext@edb83f8, xxx.RestClientTest$HttpResponseCallbackHandler@69a373fd)
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()

Comment: To test whether PowerMock is calling the correct implementation, I changed the return to instead throw an exception:

        EasyMock.expect( mockAsyncClient.execute( EasyMock.anyObject( HttpGet.class ),
                                                  EasyMock.anyObject( HttpClientContext.class ),
                                                  EasyMock.anyObject( HttpResponseCallbackHandler.class ) ) ).andThrow( new RuntimeException() );
//                .andReturn( mockFuture );

Got the same message about a missing expectation.  So, seems PowerMock is not calling what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and it's one of those problems I'm sure has hit many others...

The mock that was returning a null can be explained by the fact I mistakenly used EasyMock to create the mock and not PowerMock:

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient mockAsyncClient =
                                         EasyMock.createMock( CloseableHttpAsyncClient.class );
```

By changing that line to

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient mockAsyncClient =
                                         PowerMock.createMock( CloseableHttpAsyncClient.class );
```

the test passed.

Reason is that PowerMock owns the mocks it is used to create and can only verify behaviour on those mocks.  PowerMock wraps EasyMock and so needs visibility into the mocks under control.

For those affected by this problem, please upvote the question.  Not sure why I was down-voted but please make this answer easier to discover.

Thanks, Robin.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up here because I was trying to `whenNew(SomeClass.class).withAnyArguments()` on a class like:

```
class SomeClass {
     public SomeClass(String... args) { }
}
```

Turns out that `withAnyArguments()` doesn't match varargs.  In my case the fix was:

```
whenNew(SomeClass.class).withArguments(Matchers.<String>anyVararg()).thenReturn(myMock);
```